# storing data in local storage is not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I am trying to build a shopping cart by storing user selected product data in local storage and then populate a shopping cart by retrieving product data from local storage.  i use the code below to store product data to local storage when the add to cart button is clicked;

```js
$('#addtocart').on('click', function(e) {
  var qty = document.getElementById("p-qty").value;
  var li = $(this).parent();
  var product = {};

  product.id = productid;
  product.name = document.getElementById("nomenclature").value;
  product.price = document.getElementById("productprice").value;
  product.quantity = qty;
  addToCart(product);
});

function addToCart(product) {
  // Retrieve the cart object from local storage
  if (localStorage && localStorage.getItem('cart')) {
    var cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart'));
    cart.products.push(product);
    localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(cart));
  }

  window.location = "html/cart.html"
}
```

and I use this to retrieve stored data in cart.html page

```
var cart = localStorage.getItem("cart")
console.log("This is what is in mycart", cart)
```

This works and the product data were successfully retrieved. The problem I'm having is that I want to be able to store product data for more than 1 products unfortunately, only one product data is always available even when multiple items were added to cart. it appears as cart.products.push(product) is replacing existing product with the newly clicked product. 
I discovered that the problem I'm having is that whenever the browser is refreshed the array is cleared and starts with an empty array. I want user to be able to add multiple items which will require them going back from product page to listing page.
What am I doing wrong and how can I implement adding more than 1 products and their data to local storage?

Comment: A working example of the issue would be helpful.  On it's own, pushing an element to an array will not cause the array to lose elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your condition `localStorage && localStorage.getItem('cart')` fails on the first add, and, since the `cart` never gets added anywhere else (seemingly), this condition will always fail and nothing will ever be stored there.

Your code should be more like:

```
function addToCart(product) {
  if (localStorage) {
    var json = localStorage.getItem('cart') || '{"products": []}';
    var cart = JSON.parse(json);
    cart.products.push(product);
    localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(cart));
  }

  window.location = "html/cart.html"
}
```

Comment: for some reason, with your correction I still can not get more than one product stored in the cart. The newly clicked product replaces the existing one.

Comment: @learner101 Try doing `console.log(cart);` before pushing, and see how data changes

Comment: i discovered that it adds but the problem is whenever the browser reloads the array is cleared which defeat the purpose of being able to add multiple different items

Comment: @learner101 `localStorage` is persistent on the browser. Make sure you're not clearing caches and stuff when reloading, also make sure you're not somehow using sessionStorage instead of localStorage. You can also look up localStorage data in Chrome dev tools in **Application**

Comment: you are right i was able trace it back to where i was setting var car = {}

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using local storage, try to use IndexedDB. Because localStorage is useful for storing smaller amounts of data, it is less useful for storing larger amounts of structured data. So if you want to store significant amounts of structured data such as, in your case, storing product details, indexedDB is a better choice.

Another advantage of using IndexedDB is that you can do high performance searches using indexes.
It also provides both a synchronous and an asynchronous API. As you can see, in practice, however, all current implementations are asynchronous, and requests will not block the user interface from loading. IndexedDB is what you should choose.

for your reference:
https://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB-2/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API